# How to expand dataframe with a calculated list based on rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, expand

I have that kind of data generated by this code

```
import pandas as pd

def multichoose(n,k):
    if k < 0 or n < 0: return "Error"
    if not k: return [[0]*n]
    if not n: return []
    if n == 1: return [[k]]
    return [[0]+val for val in multichoose(n-1,k)] + \
        [[val[0]+1]+val[1:] for val in multichoose(n,k-1)]

states=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    states=states+multichoose(3,i)
df_states = pd.DataFrame(states,columns=['x1','x2','x3'])
df_states['cumsum']=df_states['x1']+df_states['x2']+df_states['x3']

x1  x2  x3  cumsum
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1
0   1   0   1
1   0   0   1
0   0   2   2
0   1   1   2
0   2   0   2
1   0   1   2
1   1   0   2
2   0   0   2
```

And I want to expand my data with this calculation

```
# For example for the first row
# in range of cumsum value + 2
[[x, y] for x in range(df_states[['cumsum']].iloc[0][0]+2) for y in range(df_states[['cumsum']].iloc[0][0]+2)]
    
#output
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

So my expected result is

```
x1  x2  x3  cumsum a1 a2
0   0   0   0      0  0
0   0   0   0      0  1
0   0   0   0      1  0
0   0   0   0      1  1
0   0   1   1      0  0
0   0   1   1      0  1
0   0   1   1      0  2
0   0   1   1      1  0
0   0   1   1      1  1
0   0   1   1      1  2
0   0   1   1      2  0
0   0   1   1      2  1
0   0   1   1      2  2
.   .   .   .      .  .
.   .   .   .      .  .
```

And in the final result, I need to implement this expansion for all rows

Thanks for help <3

Answer (score 0):

Dear trying_to_be_a_dev<

I hope you ared oing well,

```
import pandas as pd


def multichoose(n, k):
    if k < 0 or n < 0: return "Error"
    if not k: return [[0] * n]
    if not n: return []
    if n == 1: return [[k]]
    return [[0] + val for val in multichoose(n - 1, k)] + \
           [[val[0] + 1] + val[1:] for val in multichoose(n, k - 1)]


states = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    states = states + multichoose(3, i)
df_states = pd.DataFrame(states, columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3'])
df_states['cumsum'] = df_states['x1'] + df_states['x2'] + df_states['x3']
df_states['a1'] = ''
df_states['a2'] = ''

list1 = []
for i in range(len(df_states)):
    list1.append([[x, y] for x in range(df_states[['cumsum']].iloc[i][0]+2) for y in range(df_states[['cumsum']].iloc[i][0]+2)])

x = []
y = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list1[i])):
        print(list1[i][j][0])
        x.append(list1[i][j][0])
        y.append(list1[i][j][1])

for i in range(len(df_states)):
    df_states['a1'].iloc[i] = x[i]
    df_states['a2'].iloc[i] = y[i]

print(df_states)
```

[image]

For sure this is not the best solution, but it worked for me

Hope it works for you too.

Have a lovely day.

Comment: Actually I need  
x1 x2 x3 cumsum a1 a2 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 

instead of

x1 x2 x3 cumsum a1 a2
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 
1 0 0 1 1 1

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by tweaking AMIR's solution a bit. Thank you so much AMIR.

```
import pandas as pd

def multichoose(n,k):
    if k < 0 or n < 0: return "Error"
    if not k: return [[0]*n]
    if not n: return []
    if n == 1: return [[k]]
    return [[0]+val for val in multichoose(n-1,k)] + \
        [[val[0]+1]+val[1:] for val in multichoose(n,k-1)]

states=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    states=states+multichoose(3,i)
df_states = pd.DataFrame(states,columns=['x1','x2','x3'])
df_states = df_states.rename_axis('state_num').reset_index()
df_states['cumsum']=df_states['x1']+df_states['x2']+df_states['x3']
df_states

list1 = []
for i in range(len(df_states)):
    list1.append([[x, y] for x in range(df_states[['cumsum']].iloc[i][0]+2) for y in range(df_states[['cumsum']].iloc[i][0]+2)])

df_states['FIFO_LIFO']=list1
df_states.explode('FIFO_LIFO')

    state_num   x1  x2  x3  cumsum  FIFO_LIFO
0   0           0   0   0   0       [0, 0]
0   0           0   0   0   0       [0, 1]
0   0           0   0   0   0       [1, 0]
0   0           0   0   0   0       [1, 1]
1   1           0   0   1   1       [0, 0]
... ...         ... ... ... ...     ...
9   9           2   0   0   2       [2, 3]
9   9           2   0   0   2       [3, 0]
9   9           2   0   0   2       [3, 1]
9   9           2   0   0   2       [3, 2]
9   9           2   0   0   2       [3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative implementation, using some builtin methods from the standard library, in particular [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

First a different version of `multichoose` using [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) in combination with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as combos, product

def multichoose(n, k):
    choices = []
    for combo in combos(range(n), k):
        count = Counter(combo)
        choices.append([count.get(i, 0) for i in range(n)])
    return list(reversed(choices))
```

For small `n` and `k` your version is slightly faster, but when the numbers become a bigger this version seems faster (at least here). The `list(...)` in the return is just for printing, you don't actually need it in your context. Is the exact ordering of the choices important? If not, then the `reversed(...)` could be removed too.

Then regarding your question: You could pack all the required row-producing logic in a generator function that uses [`product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
def rows(n, m):
    num = 0
    for k in range(m):
        choices = []
        for combo in combos(range(n), k):
            count = Counter(combo)
            choices.append(tuple(count.get(i, 0) for i in range(n)))
        for choice in reversed(choices):
            for a1, a2 in product(range(k + 2), repeat=2):
                yield (num,) + choice + (k, a1, a2)
            num += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(
    rows(3, 3), columns=['state_num', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'cumsum', 'a1', 'a2']
)
```

(Again: If the order isn't that important this could be made simpler.)

Result for your example:

```
     state_num  x1  x2  x3  cumsum  a1  a2
0            0   0   0   0       0   0   0
1            0   0   0   0       0   0   1
2            0   0   0   0       0   1   0
3            0   0   0   0       0   1   1
4            1   0   0   1       1   0   0
..         ...  ..  ..  ..     ...  ..  ..
122          9   2   0   0       2   2   3
123          9   2   0   0       2   3   0
124          9   2   0   0       2   3   1
125          9   2   0   0       2   3   2
126          9   2   0   0       2   3   3

[127 rows x 7 columns]
```